# android system-app update restoring to default after reboot

Tags: android, system, reboot

Hei,

I've written a system app which is included in my system image. When I run update with the same package name and certificate, the system image is read-only so it will generate a new app in the data image with inherited system permissions.
Everything works fine, but after reboot, the update is gone. There is just the default application installed, without a clue there was an update installed before.

Do I miss something? Do I have to set a property in the manifest of the update, or is there a problem with my platform and the application works just fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to increment the `android:versionCode`. The platform will delete the apk from data image if the version is not bigger than that of in system image.